# Missing 2 required positional arguments for flavors and scoops?

Tags: python

I have this program that has two exceptions one for number of scoops and one for flavors. When I try to run the program I get a type error: main() missing 2 required positional arguments: ‘flavors’ and ‘scoops’

How do I fix this?

Code:

```
class FlavorError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, flavors, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)
        self.flavors = flavors

class ScoopsError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, scoops, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, scoops, message)
        self.scoops = scoops

def main(flavors, scoops):
    
    flavors= " "
    scoops = " "
    holdings = " "

    flavors = input("Enter a flavor of ice cream: ")
    print()
    if flavors not in ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry', 'Mint', 'Pistachio', 'Spumoni']:
        raise FlavorError(flavors, "is not on the menu.")
    scoops = int(input("Enter the number of scoops: "))
    print()
    if scoops > 3:
        raise ScoopsError(scoops, 'We do not offer that many scoops!')

    holdings = input("Would you like a cone or bowl? ")
    print()
    print(scoops , "scoops of" , flavors , "in a" , holdings)

main()
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation.  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: Simply change `def main(flavors, scoops):` to `def main():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Down there the last line, `main()` has to have 2 arguments, change it to something like `main('vanilla', 4)`

edit:
As pointed out in the comments, you should just delete it in the function, so that it looks like this

```py
def main():
    
    flavors= " "
    scoops = " "
    holdings = " "

    flavors = input("Enter a flavor of ice cream: ")
    print()
    if flavors not in ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry', 'Mint', 'Pistachio', 'Spumoni']:
        raise FlavorError(flavors, "is not on the menu.")
    scoops = int(input("Enter the number of scoops: "))
    print()
    if scoops > 3:
        raise ScoopsError(scoops, 'We do not offer that many scoops!')

    holdings = input("Would you like a cone or bowl? ")
    print()
    print(scoops , "scoops of" , flavors , "in a" , holdings)
```

Comment: The function doesn't use the parameters, it prompts the user for these values.

Comment: There's no point in doing that, since the values get overwritten with `" "` anyway. They just need to be removed as parameters in the function definition.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it